# numpy memory error converting a big dataset from list to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am preprocessing a large dataset for an NN training. My dataset is accumulated in `features = list()`.

When attempting `features = np.array(features)` I am getting:

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 29.6 GiB for an array with shape (37990, 605, 173) and data type float64

I have seen a number of solutions in other posts, like [saving and reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032200/converting-python-list-to-numpy-array-inplace/39072596), which did not work due to `np.save` converting to an array first, or [using uint8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342161/memory-error-while-converting-list-to-numpy-array) for images, or a lower memory format when possible.

The problem is, that my input is a tensor bot, not an image. I am not sure what are the maximal values and due to my classification task, I don't know if I can use another format. I am trying to avoid using a keras generator due to the implementation overhead. So, my question is, is there a way of handling this dataset without the use of a generator?

Comment: np.arrays do not use more memory than a list, the problem is that during conversion, you need to hold both array and list in memory and you do not seem to have enough RAM for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's mmap() support: this will back the data by a file on disk, while still acting like a normal numpy array. So it doesn't have to fit in memory.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/mmap-vs-zarr-hdf5/ for explanation of how this works.

Comment: I don't think I understand your links. If I am not mistaken, this is for an `ndarray`, which is already saved on the disk. My data is a list and I can not convert it into an `ndarray` due to size errors. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You should create an empty mmaped() ndarray, then copy the values over into it (arr = memmap("myarray", "w+"); arr[:] = features[:], something like that).

Comment: Does not work. I am initializing the `memmap` array. On the copy command, it gives the same error.

Comment: Try arr[:] = features, without the extra list copy.